# Quickbooks: how to keep track of mortgage installments as expenses?

Tags: investing, mortgage, accounting, expenses, quickbooks

I am new to Quickbooks. Anyone can help answer this quick question? I need some help figure out mortgage installments bookkeeping rules.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about QuickBooks, but in Quicken I just set up the loan account and record payments as transfers to it. It may not be getting the principal/interest split *exactly* right, but it's close enough until year-end taxes.